# Getting Images Dynamically In Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load multiple images when button is clicked.

This is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
           $('#img').html('<img src="img ' + $(this).val() + '.jpg" width="200px">');
    });
});
```

Here how to use for loop to get all images from img folder

html code:

```
<body>
<div id="img"></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>
</body>
```

Comment: $(this).val() will return value of button clicked. Do you want this or some other values like images name?

Comment: based on what you will load multiple images?

Comment: You have to use AJAX in order to get all images from folder.

Comment: You are updating the `.html()` so it will load 1 image at a time,  instead you should use `append()` property on `$('#img')`. So it will append the result one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where your "img folder" is, so I have defined a few variables for you to update their values.

Anyway, the code would be:

```
// update these
var imagesFolder = "myFolder";
var imagesSources = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"];

$("button").click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imagesSources.length; i++) {
        $('#img').append('<img src="' + imagesFolder + '/' + imagesSources[i] + '.jpg">');
    }   
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to get images directly from folder without storing in an array

Comment: Well, yes, but you would need to read from that folder to discover which files are there. JavaScript is not able to do that without user input. If your files are on a server, you can write a method to read file names from the folder and return it as an array of names to your front-end, which will then display the images.